# What is the port that is used by localhost?

Tags: localhost

I'm using [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server. What is the port that is used by this application?

I want to share the contents of it to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be specific your question. WAMP is Window, Apache, MySQL and PHP.

Apache uses port 80 and MySQL uses port 3306 (on Windows).

How do you want to share? Via a web browser or a Windows network?

Comment: via web browser

Comment: you've to open port 80 from firewall.

Comment: not only this, you have to ensure that the services are not bound to 127.0.0.1 (localhost). they must be bound to an ip-address reachable from the outside